# Are apps created from the CC data dump ok to add?

Tags: discussion, questions, meta

I've created a few apps in the past using the CC data dumps that I can't move over to the API at this point. It seems like the stackapps site is meant to be the place to find apps for Stack Exchange sites. Is the intent to limit it only to apps created with the API or is it open to all?

As a side note, the main reason I'm not able to move the apps over is lack of search. I know the common response is to use Google or another engine but that doesn't seem viable. Some of the apps may not be fully baked but others may find them useful when creating their own apps.

**Edit:** Any thoughts on a good tag to signal that an app uses CC data? I was thinking CCDD but I'm not sure if that is too cryptic.

Comment: ++ signs the petition.

Comment: I'm curious, why is using Google for general search not viable?

Comment: @kevin - usage of the cc dumps for general search is not a typical use case. they are static and dated. the more common use is for analytics and, as carson points out, targeted querying which would not be described as general search. For 'general search' I always use google. The built-in stack search is very not effective.

Comment: @carson - [google's ajax api](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/terms.html) allows arbitrary consumption, unless I misread the TOS.

Comment: @Kevin I think that depends on what you mean by arbitrary. There are a number of clauses in there that make it clear they want you to show the results as they are returned in their entirety. The results may contain tracking URLs that will mask the actual true URL and some results may be advertisements.

Comment: @carson - I read the google TOS so as to allow consumption for data purposes, provided you always go off of `result[0]` (bah, lawyers and not being one).  Presentation of results is restricted, though.  You could always use [Bing](http://www.bing.com/developers/tou.aspx) which explicitly exempts manipulation of web search results.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think **listing apps that use the data dump are fine** -- it's an expansion of scope for stackapps, but then [so was adding support for browser scripts](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/stack-apps-and-scripts/).

Generally anything third-party and programmery that makes the network more awesome should go here.

Comment: Old guidance was "pre-scripts."  In light of the relaxed listing rules, can't see why we wouldn't also allow data dump backed [app]s.